# How to convert Record to Table Record in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to convert JOOQ's Result set of  Record to a List of Table Record. Is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`Result.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#into%28org.jooq.Table%29). An example:

```
Result<?> result = create.fetch(...);
Table<MyRecord> MY_TABLE = ...
Result<MyRecord> other = result.into(MY_TABLE);
```

As [`Result`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html) implements `List`, this should do what you need